# Is there a way I could call my own Lua library from Luau?

Tags: lua, luau

I am thinking if there is any way I could use Luau outside of Roblox for much more purposes. But its extremely limited standard library doesn't let me do anything big.

Is there any way I could do something like this?

```lua
-- main.luau
local m = require("test")
m.foo()
```

```lua
-- test.lua
local m = {}
m.__index = m

function m.foo()
    io.write("bar")
end

return m
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Standard `require()` is removed from Luau and replaced with Roblox-specific function loading ModuleScript.
But it seems that `luau` standalone interpreter [searches for](https://github.com/Roblox/luau/blob/d458d240cdc07765cfe6bd81417faa3f642d0d75/CLI/Repl.cpp#L133-L139) `your_module.lua` and `your_module.luau` files **in the current directory** when you `require("your_module")`